# Interacting with PostgreSQL server in Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm creating a Docker image based on the `postgres` image and I'm trying to interact with it like this:

```
FROM postgres:9.6

USER postgres
RUN createuser foo
```

However, this results in the following error while building:

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

How do I properly connect to the PostgreSQL server from within this container?

Answer (score 0):

The postgres server isn't running during the `docker build` process, so trying to connect to it with a `RUN` statement in your Dockerfile isn't going to work.

If you want to create users or databases or extensions, etc, you need to do that at runtime.  There are a few options available, and which one you choose depends on exactly what you're trying to do.

If you just need to create a user and/or database that differs from the default, you can do that via environment variables as described in [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).

To create a user other than `postgres`:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_USER=foo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret [...] postgres
```

To create a database other than the default (which will match the name of `POSTGRES_USER`):

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_DB=mydbname [...] postgres
```

If you need to do anything more complicated, take a look at the "How to extend this image" section of the documentation. You can place shell scripts or sql scripts into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and they will be executed during container startup.  There is an example there that demonstrates how to create an additional database using this mechanism.